# Error handing in For loop - Subscript out of range

Tags: vba

I am trying to loop through an String array, locate the row and column index using .Find method. If the method doesn't return anything, I want to capture the the error.

Below is my code. The problem I am having is that i keep getting the "Subscript out of range" error in Err: when variable i gets to the UBound(arrRDS) + 1 value which will stop the loop.

```
        On Error GoTo Err:
        For i = LBound(arrRDS) To UBound(arrRDS)
            
            sAcnt = Split(arrRDS(i), ";")(1)
            sAnl = Split(arrRDS(i), ";")(2)

            r = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=sAcnt, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            c = .Range("6:6").Find(What:=sAnl, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c) = "x"

        Next

        Application.StatusBar = False
        
Err:
        Debug.Print arrRDS(i)
        Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` will not reach `UBound(arrRDS) + 1` inside the loop, so I would guess it's `Debug.Print arrRDS(i)` which is erroring, and that's because you have no `Exit Sub/Function` preventing your code from running right into your error handler (and `i` will be out of range at that point, since the loop only exits when `i` > `UBound(arrRDS)` ).

```vb
        On Error GoTo Err:
        For i = LBound(arrRDS) To UBound(arrRDS)
            
            sAcnt = Split(arrRDS(i), ";")(1)
            sAnl = Split(arrRDS(i), ";")(2)

            r = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=sAcnt, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            c = .Range("6:6").Find(What:=sAnl, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c) = "x"

        Next

        Application.StatusBar = False
        Exit Sub                       '############
        
Err:
        Debug.Print arrRDS(i)
        Resume Next
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's the debug.print statement that's throwing the error. But I want to continue the loop, logging all the errors rather than stopping the process

Comment: Did you try the code I posted, with the addition of `Exit Sub` to prevent normal execution from running into your error handler?

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. It's working perfectly for me!